# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

1.`mapGetters` are working.
2.fetchTiles called in `mounted` life cycle of  hello.vue is working
3.`fetchId` called in onClick method of click.vue is **not working**
what could be the problem?.

Hello.vue

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
import { startEditor, addNodeBoard } from "../utilities/utilities";
import Drawflow from "drawflow";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      editor: null,
    
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  computed: mapGetters(["allTiles"]),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchTiles"]),
   
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchTiles();
  },
};
</script>
```

click.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card-devices" v-on:click="onClick">
    <div class="body" v-html="symbol"></div>
    <span> {{ names }} </span>
    <div class="misc">
      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      ids: "",
    };
  },
  props: {
    names: String,
    symbol: String,
    editors: Object,
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchId"]),
    onClick: function() {
      this.ids = this.editors.node_selected.getAttribute("id");
      this.fetchId(this.ids);
      console.log("clicked");
    },
   
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.fas {
  padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
.misc {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.card-devices {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
</style>
```

store is called in main.js

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import tiles from './modules/tiles'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  
  modules: {
    tiles
  }
})
```

tiles.js

```
const state = {
  tiles: [...tilesCollections],
  editor: {},
};

const getters = {
  allTiles: (state) => state.tiles,
};

const actions = {
  fetchTiles({ commit }) {
    commit("setTiles", tilesCollections);
  },
  fetchId({ commit }, ids) {
    console.log(ids);
    commit("setEditor", ids);
  },
};
const mutations = {
  setEditor: (state, editor) => (state.editor = editor),
  setTiles: (state, tiles) => (state.tiles = tiles),
};
export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Yes or no:  Does it work in `mounted`?  Does it work on click?  Probably the prop is not ready yet when you try to use it.  Do you load the prop async in the parent?

Comment: Let me edit my question. it is not working in `onclick`. in the case of `mounted`, it is working. props are ready because I can log it in the console when the component is mounted.

Comment: Do you see the logs when clicking?

Comment: If you are asking whether  the  onclick function is working, yes I can console.log editor in onclick function

Comment: Where are you getting the `dispatch` error mentioned in the title?  I don't see any `dispatch` in the code

Comment: in my click.vue. when I click on div which has classname card-devices it shows dispatch error. it occurs when it calls `fetchId()` in onclick function

Comment: I don't know, I can't reproduce the error. Maybe you can post the app or a simplified version to https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Looks like fetchId is an action in a store module, but you are calling it in mapActions on main store

Answer (score 0):

The module is called tile but in your import you have used tiles:

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import tiles from './modules/tile'
    Vue.use(Vuex)
    
    export default new Vuex.Store({
      
      modules: {
        tiles
      }
    })
```

FetchId is an action in the tile module so:

```
...mapActions("tiles", ["fetchId"]),
```

Comment: the file is called tile.js and the import import tiles from './modules/tiles'

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo from my part . Actually it is tiles.js. I'Il edit the post. if it was a typo, vue would have shown import error right?